# Naming identified scrolls only works sometimes?

Tags: nethack

I'm trying to `#name` a few of my already identified scrolls in my inventory in case I'm hit by amnesia (by type), however naming fails to work sometimes.

I now have `an uncursed scroll of enchant armor named enchant armor` in my inventory (as expected), but `an uncursed scroll of identify` and `an uncursed scroll of teleportation` seem to resist naming. What am I doing wrong?

nethack version is 3.6.0.

Comment: It sounds like you named the individual scroll of enchant armor, and are trying to type-name the other ones; your names will show up in discoveries (hit \) but not in inventory since you know what they actually are.